# Transformer works perfectly during training while works terrible in inference?

Tags: pytorch, compression, transformer-model

I am adding three layers of transformer in my architecture and the task is compression. The train validation and loss work nicely during training while during the inference it is terrible and the accuracy drops significantly. I am not sure if it has something to do with overfitting or not but the plot at least doesn't show (if I am not wrong). How could it be possible the transformer works great during training but works terribly during the inference?

```
class Transformer(nn.Module):
            """ transformer"""
            def __init__(self, in_dim):
                super(Transformer, self).__init__()
                self.pooling = ME.MinkowskiAvgPooling(kernel_size=3,stride=3,dimension=3)
                self.linear = ME.MinkowskiLinear(in_dim,in_dim)
                self.relu = ME.MinkowskiReLU(inplace=True)
                self.convmlp = ME.MinkowskiConvolution(in_dim,in_dim,kernel_size=1,stride=1,bias=True,dimension=3)
                
            def forward(self, x):

                x = x + self.relu(self.linear(self.pooling(x)))
                x = x + self.relu(self.convmlp(x))
                return x
```

[image]

Comment: You need to determine if the issue is the model itself or a difference between your test set and your inference data

Comment: @Karl if the issue is about model itself why it doesn't show itself during training?